# How to turn off tooltips on hover

Tags: visual-studio-code

[This was originally asked back in December but still has no answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109539/how-do-i-turn-off-the-tooltips)

To see the problem in action, watch [funfunfunction's "ESNex Pipeline Operator" video starting around 6:27](https://youtu.be/dYQIkV2L-eg?t=6m27s).